# how to unwrap this simple window frame?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm fairly new to 3d modelling and I've been working on my UV unwrapping lately, I've had problems with this object for a few days and was wondering if one of the pros / semi pros can help me out...

The object is a simple window frame.
[image: Window Frame]

The issue is with the inside part of the frame has warped UVs as you can tell from the photo below. Where else do I need to mark a seam to fix this?

[image: UV Map]

Comment: UV>Smart UV Project is probably sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your unwrap isn't the seam placement, it's that you didn't uncheck `Fill Holes` in the unwrap dialog.

This is probably way overkill, but here is the layout I came up with that uses the least amount of visible seams as possible:

Top:

[image: top]

Bottom:

[image: bottom]

The layout:

[image: layout]